# Error: Sender xxx.testnet does not have enough balance 9.99991607015 for operation costing 100.0000861846776875

Tags: near

I am currently doing a course on NEAR on a site called [dacade.org](https://dacade.org/communities/near/courses/near-101/learning-modules/b52ba9f1-caac-4339-96ed-fad3b1ab6bbd#:%7E:text=4.3%20Create%20a%20Subaccount)
In the tutorial, after creating a top level account on the NEAR testnet, I create a sub account.

```
$ near create-account contract.xxx.testnet --masterAccount xxx.testnet
```

When I do this, it returns an error that my balance is insufficient.

```
An error occured
Error: Sender yukasaito.testnet does not have enough balance 9.99991607015 for operation costing 100.0000861846776875
```

The first amount given by testnet to the top level account is 10NEAR.

On the other hand, I am told that I need 100.0000861846776875 NEAR to create the sub-account.

Is the only way to prepare the balance by creating multiple top level accounts?

I would like to know if there is any other better way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the --initialBalance flag
The 100 come from half of what was previously given automatically to new testnet accounts, recently that changed to 10 (previously 200) the cli is not yet updated to reflect that change.

`$ near create-account contract.xxx.testnet --masterAccount xxx.testnet --initialBalance 5`

Comment: Excuse my additional question.
Was there an announcement anywhere that the price was reduced from 200 NEAR to 10 NEAR? I could not find it on the website or on NEAR discode, maybe my search was not the right way to do it...

Comment: No, it was silently made change but it makes sense since probably the majority of the mainnet wallet hold less than 200 near there are not whole lot of reasons why would you need so much on each testnet account